# Create a dynamic Union type with mapped property

Tags: typescript, types

I have the following types

```js
enum Types {
  Email = 'email',
  Checkbox = 'checkbox',
}

type MappedValues = {
  [Types.Email]: string;
  [Types.Checkbox]: boolean;
};

type T1<T extends Types> = { type: T } & {
  [key in T]: MappedValues[T];
};

type T2 = T1<Types.Email | Types.Checkbox>
```

With the above example `T2` is:

```
{
  type: 'email' | 'checkbox',
  email: string,
  checkbox: boolean
}
```

But I am looking for:

```
{
  type: 'email',
  email: string
} | {
  type: 'checkbox',
  checkbox: boolean
}
```

I went through the whole typescript documentation about typings and discover a lot of interesting things but nothing about my specific case.

Is it possible to do it or do I have to change my base types (`Types`, `MappedValues`) ?

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to create a type with all the possible values:

```js
type T1<T extends Types> = {
  [key in T]: {
    type: key,
    data: MappedValues[key]
  }
}

type T2 = T1<Types.Email | Types.Checkbox>
```

Here `T2` is:

```
{
  email: {
    type: 'email',
    data: string
  },
  checkbox: {
    type: 'checkbox',
    data: boolean
  }
}
```

Then you can use your generic to index this map to transform it into an union:

```js
type T1<T extends Types> = {
  [key in T as string]: {
    type: key;
  } & {
    [property in key]: MappedValues[key];
  };
}[T];
```

And `T2` become:

```
({
    type: Types.Email;
} & {
    email: string;
}) | ({
    type: Types.Checkbox;
} & {
    checkbox: boolean;
})
```